# Alfresco sdk 3 - acces non displayed form variable

Tags: json, forms, workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have simple form with differents fields:

workflow-validation-model.xml (platform-jar):

```
 <types>
    <type name="wfvd:activitiReviewTask">
        <parent>wf:activitiReviewTask</parent>

        <properties>
            <property name="wfvd:retourMedecin">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="wfvd:nomService">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="wfvd:newPatient">
                <title>Créer un nouveau patient</title>
                <type>d:boolean</type>
            </property> 

            <property name="wfvd:idPatient">
                <title>Identifiant du patient</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>

            <property name="wfvd:nomPatient">
                <title>Nom du patient</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
  ....
```

their visibility are defined in workflow-config.xml (share-jar):

```
 <forms>
        <form>
        <edit-form template="/2-column-edit-form.ftl" />
            <field-visibility>

                <show id="wfvd:patients" />
                <show id="wfvd:newPatient" />
                <show id="wfvd:nomPatient" />
                <show id="wfvd:prenomPatient" />
                <show id="wfvd:dateNaissance" />
                <show id="wfvd:idPatient"/>
                <show id="wfvd:medecin" />
                <show id="wfvd:typologie"/>
                <show id="wfvd:dateDocument" />
                <show id="bpm:priority" />
                <!-- <show id="packageItems" /> -->
                <show id="wfvd:commentaireSecretaire" />
                <show id="wfvd:commentaireMedecin" />

                <show id="wfvd:reviewOutcomeMedecin" />

            </field-visibility>
```

Some of them are not displayed (unnecessary for user) but now, I need to work with one of them.

I see it in json reponse :

[image]

but I don't know how to acces it in javascript.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your variable in workflow activiti script task listeners,

which executes the javascript code of script tag.

```
 <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
            //javascript code
            ]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
```

Like this : 
In same task :

> task.getVariableLocal('wfvd_nomService');

In same/other task :

> execution.getVariable("wfvd_nomService");

Comment: thank you but I would like to use it in share javascript : i use jQuery for variables that are displayed on form but i don't know how to access variables that are not displayed. So i solve my problem by adding variable on form : `show id="wfvd:nomService" />` and i have used jQuery to hide it : `$('#page_x002e_data-form_x002e_task-edit_x0023_default_prop_wfvd_nomService').hide();`

Comment: if you wanted to hide then you can override the form by defining in share-config-custom.xml as replace=true.